# FFmpeg failed to transcode

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, drupal

I have successfully installed Video Module with FFmpeg/avconv in local machine. My current version of FFmpeg is "0.6.0-svn".

I have downloaded the [video preset package from drupal.org](http://drupal.org/project/video_presets) for FFMPEG and installed it. Now when I am uploading any video of type WebM, MP3 or WMV then thumbnail is getting generated successfully.

After saving the node it gives me following error:

> Something went wrong with transcoding big_buck_bunny.mp4. Please check your recent log entries for further debugging.

After going to recent log entries I found this thing:

> PHPVideoToolkit error: Execute error. It was not possible to encode "C:\xampp\htdocs\MusicHouse\sites\default\files\videos\original\big_buck_bunny.mp4" as FFmpeg returned an error.

Note, however the error was encountered on the second pass of the encoding process and the first pass appear to go fine. The error is with the video codec of the input file. FFmpeg reports the error to be

> Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height.

I need the Video module to work in my project as it works with the most file formats and generates thumbnail with open source FFmpeg.

Comment: I would suggest you use a version of FFmpeg that's not ancient. Download a recent static build from their homepage please. The error message you get is not the full, uncut log. Please include the exact command you're using and the full output.

Comment: Was also asked on [drupal.se] and closed: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59998/not-able-to-transcode-video-with-ffmpeg